# Use SVG image on website with rounded corners - showing white for rounded area

Tags: html, svg

I am creating a very simple React page with an SVG image on it.  That SVG image has round corners.  I can open it up in GIMP and see the rounded corners shown.

[image]

Now I add it to my website like this:

```
import cardBackR from '../img/cards/2B.svg'
...
<img className='card' src={cardBackR} />
```

And then when I view the page with the card over a background image, the rounded corners show as white:
[image]

Here is the full SVG code of that image.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="card" face="2B" height="3.5in" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="-120 -168 240 336" width="2.5in">
<defs>
<pattern id="B2" width="6" height="6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<path d="M3 0L6 3L3 6L0 3Z" fill="red"></path>
</pattern>
</defs>
<rect width="239" height="335" x="-119.5" y="-167.5" rx="12" ry="12" fill="white" stroke="black"></rect>
<rect fill="url(#B2)" width="216" height="312" x="-108" y="-156" rx="12" ry="12"></rect>
</svg>
```

I've tested this in both Firefox and Chrome.  Any ideas what is causing the rounded corners to fail?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  It's likely that wherever the problem is, it's not in the code you've shown us.  https://jsfiddle.net/L7az5bsq/

Comment: Wait, `img[src]` should be an URL, not a SVG document source code. How are you even getting this result? (Also, as Brad says, using a `svg` element directly, rather than as an `img`, definitely preserves transparency.)

Comment: Why not just use `border-radius` for this?

Comment: @Brad you were right.  I got unlucky in the choice of classes to add to that element.  Look what Bootstrap is doing: `.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}`

Answer (score 0):

SVG in an IMG src should work fine, provided you escape the **#** with **%23**

```html
<style>
  body{
    background:green;
  }
</style>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
class='card' face='2B' height='3.5in' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='-120 -168 240 336' width='2.5in'>
<defs><pattern id='B2' width='6' height='6' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
<path d='M3 0L6 3L3 6L0 3Z' fill='red'></path></pattern></defs>
<rect width='239' height='335' x='-119.5' y='-167.5' rx='12' ry='12' fill='white' stroke='black'></rect>
<rect fill='url(%23B2)' width='216' height='312' x='-108' y='-156' rx='12' ry='12'></rect>
</svg>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.  I unfortunately picked a poor name for my class.  That is a special class in Bootstrap and that was adding the following CSS:

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```